# How to manually set link-local address in Debian?

Tags: ipv6, ip-address, link-local

I'm trying to use manually assigned link-local addresses to have more meaningful routing tables. I disabled auto configuration for all interfaces in /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf=0
```

and configured all addresses in /etc/network/interfaces

```
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
iface eth1 inet6 static
    address fe80::A dev eth1
    netmask 64

iface eth1 inet6 static
    address 2002:db8::A
    netmask 64
    gateway fe80::B
    dns-server 2002:db8::C
```

When I ifup the interface however, not only I get second - auto generated - link-local address, there is also an error message displayed:

```
Waiting for DAD... Error: inet6 prefix is expected rather than "fe80::A dev eth1/64".
Error: inet6 prefix is expected rather than "fe80::A dev eth1/64".
Done
```

Is it possible to achieve what I want, or am I forced to stick with EUI-64?

Comment: I don't think `dev eth1` is supposed to be there. And btw. when you write `2002:db8:` did you mean `2001:db8:` or `2002:c000:0201:`? Also I don't know if multiple `iface eth1 inet6` sections is supported.

Comment: You're right, "dev eth1" breaks everything. Also I ment 2001:db8 and multiple iface sections for the same interface are supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, disabling autoconfiguration of link-local addresses doesn't seem to be working in stretch, so the autoconfigured address needs to be removed. Below is the working /etc/network/interfaces config

```
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
iface eth1 inet6 static
    address fe80::a
    netmask 64

iface eth1 inet6 static
    address 2001:db8::a
    netmask 64
    gateway fe80::b
    dns-server 2001:db8::c

    post-up ip address del fe80::a:b:c:d/64 dev eth1
```